# find whether given (x,y) coordinate exists in SVG Image?

Tags: svg

I wanted to find whether a given point exists in image area. Image width and height is 40. The four corners are (10,10),(50,10),(10,50),(50,50). Is there a way to find a given (x,y) exists or not in the area?

Comment: Are you asking for a solution for an arbitrary polygon or are you asking us to actually type that any point with both x and y values between 10 and 50 is within your specific square?

Comment: I am working on preventing overlapping of SVG images. If the 'DroppedImage' (x, y) exists in any of the already existing images, do not allow drop.
Yes, I am looking second solution.

Comment: Why aren't you just writing the few lines of JavaScript code that would check to see whether the point is within the rectangle?

Comment: Perhaps the OP is asking about testing for transparent pixels in an SVG `<image>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check whether point lies inside the rect or not, i uses line equation and compare the point with all four lines.
The key to this approach is the sequence of points.

check the below code:-

```
 function isPointInside(fourPointsArray, pointToCheck) {

                        var counter = 0;

                                var ele = pointToCheck;
                                var A, B, C, D, p1, p2, indx;
                                for (var k = 0; k < fourPointsArray.length; k++) {
                                        p1 = fourPointsArray[k];
                                        indx = k + 1;
                                        if (indx >= fourPointsArray.length)
                                                indx = 0;
                                        p2 = fourPointsArray[indx];

                                        A = -(p2.y - p1.y);
                                        B = p2.x - p1.x;
                                        C = -(A * p1.x + B * p1.y);
                                        D = A * ele.x + B * ele.y + C;

                                        if (D >= 0) {
                                                counter++;
                                        }
                                }
                                if (counter >= fourPointsArray.length) {
                                        return true;
                                }


                        return false;
                }

var arraypoints=[{x:10,y:10},{x:50,y:10},{x:50,y:50},{x:10,y:50}];   
                var pointtocheck={
                    x:5,
                    y:10                            
                }
                var flag=isPointInside(arraypoints,pointtocheck);
                console.log(flag);
```